# How to format a number so that dot appears in the thousands?

Tags: javascript, aura, datatable, format, column

I have a datatable defined as follows:

```
<lightning:datatable data="{!v.mydata }" columns="{!v.mycolumns}" keyField="id" hideCheckboxColumn="true" resizeColumnDisabled="true" 
                     onsort="{!c.actualizarOrdenado}"
                     sortedBy="{!v.sortedBy}"
                     sortedDirection="{!v.sortedDirection}"
                     onrowaction="{!c.redirectToFacturas}"
                         />
```

And the target column defined in this way:

```
{
    type: "number",
    label: listaColumnas[i].label,
    fieldName: listaColumnas[i].apiName,
    editable:listaColumnas[i].editable,
    sortable: true,
    typeAttributes: {
        minimumFractionDigits:  2
    }
}
```

The problem is that for example 1000.00 shows as 1000,00, and i need to show it as 1.000,00
Curiously, when the number has more than  4 digits it works (for example 20000.00 shows correctly as 20.000,00) Some suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Experiment in this [lightning-formatted-number/example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-number/example) page - you can edit the HTML there - to establish the right values for:

- maximum-fraction-digits
- maximum-significant-digits
- minimum-fraction-digits
- minimum-integer-digits
- minimum-significant-digits

and then transfer those results to the `typeAttributes` of your table following the alternate naming convention that `minimumFractionDigits` provides an example of.